# python manage.py collectstatic - 0 static files copied

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

Good day, I'm trying to run the command on the bash of pythonanywhere: `python manage.py collectstatic` below I paste the output. Any suggestion?

```
(science.pythonanywhere.com) 12:36 ~/science.pythonanywhere.com (master)$ python manage.py collectstatic
You have requested to collect static files at the destination location as specified in your settings:
/home/science/science.pythonanywhere.com/static
This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes

0 static files copied to '/home/science/science.pythonanywhere.com/static', 130 unmodified.
```

Answer (score 4):

That means there is no changes, all your static files already  exist in the destination

Comment: I`m following a tutorial and must copy the file at this point. Following what the tutorial says: Servers like PythonAnywhere like to treat "static files" (like CSS files) differently from Python files, because they can optimise for them to be loaded faster. As a result, whenever we make changes to our CSS files, we need to run an extra command on the server to tell it to update them. The command is called collectstatic. So after give the command collectstatic something must happen. Also the look of the web site on the remote server is worse from the one on my local server.

Comment: Collectstatic creates a copy of all your static files (css, images, js...) from static dir to static root. Paths are defined in django settings